# Структура веб-приложения: где обычно хранятся xml файлы?

Tags: web-apps, java

Привет, это снова я. У меня получилось вот такое приложение:
[image]
Да, я всё ещё мучаю тот туториал с сайта spring'a. В нём было сказано положить applicationContext.xml и springapp-servlet.xml в WEB-INF. После того, как я заменил Jdbc на Hibernate, чтобы IDEA помогала мне с запросами, она создала hibernate.cfg.xml и предложила по умолчанию положить в resources. Это ок? Есть какие-нибудь рекомендации, где что хранить? Или на вкус и цвет все фломастеры разные?

Comment: Не мучились бы вы со старыми туториалами. Попробуйте spring-boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не мучились бы вы такими вопросами. От того, где лежит файл, меняется только способ его получения.

Если файл лежит в `WEB-INF`, то там же он будет лежать и в итоговом web-приложении и тогда путь к нему нужно будет получать через контекст сервлета:

```
servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/myfile");
```

Если файл лежит в `resources`, тогда он будет доступен из `classpath`:

```
someClass.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myfile");
```

Выбирайте, какой из способов подходит вам в вашем конкретном случае.